# How to show a spinner while loading an image in homepage?

Tags: reactjs, image, spinner

I am trying to add a spinner in my home page. I have already declared another component:

```
<Loading></Loading>
```

where I included the spinner.
Now, how do I call this above-mentioned component in my home page banner section?

Comment: Welcome to SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

hi to display a spinner you need to load something, for most any static data will fill to display really fast.
loading is good when you load big data or get data from Data Base.

here is a good component of loading:

```
import React from 'react';

import './LoadingSpinner.css';

const LoadingSpinner = props => {
  return (
    <div className={`${props.asOverlay && 'loading-spinner__overlay'}`}>
      <div className="lds-dual-ring"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadingSpinner;
```

some CSS:

```
.lds-dual-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #510077;
  border-color: #510077 transparent #510077 transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.loading-spinner__overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

now, to use it(example of loading users from database):

```
const Users = () => {
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const [loadedUsers, setLoadedUsers] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        //with fetch, the default request type is GET request
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/users"
        );
        setLoadedUsers(responseData.users); 
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, [sendRequest]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {isLoading && (
        <div className="center">
          <LoadingSpinner />
        </div>
      )}
      {/* we need to render loadedUsers only if not empty*/}
      {!isLoading && loadedUsers && <UsersList items={loadedUsers} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```